# Product formula

Tags: calculus, number-theory, products

I just want to ask about this formula:
$$
\prod_{j=1}^n(1-q^j) = \;\;?
$$ with $|q|<1$ and $q \neq 1$.

Does it represent some particular product, function or partials infinite product?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a minor point but, if $|q| \lt 1$, then it's redundant to also specify $q \neq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a special case of the [*q*-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol).